# How to use datediff function yii dataprovider criteria

Tags: php, yii

I have datediff in yii dataprovider criteria but it returns the wrong result.

```
$expirations = new CActiveDataProvider('Images',array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        //'condition'=>"t.status='Active'",
        //'select'=> array("t.*,  ",new CDbExpression("DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME(t.copyright_expiration_date ) , now( ) ) as expiry")),
        'select'=> array("t.*, DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME(t.copyright_expiration_date ) , now( ) ) as expiry ",new CDbExpression("DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME(t.copyright_expiration_date ) , now( ) ) as expiry")),
        'with'=>array("catalog","collection_count")
    ),
    "sort"=>$sort,
    'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>$perpage,),
));
```

Comment: What's the result? And what do you expect to be the result?

Answer (score 1):

what does it mean "wrong result" ?

But anyway I guess it is not possible this way. For each field you want to select I think you need a variable of this to be present in the class. So you would need to craete a variable in the class `Images` called `$expiry`

```
class Images ... {

  public $expiry;

...
}
```